# How do I make my pets stop sitting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I loaded up my survival backup world, which I have pets. When I opened the world, I can't make my pets stop sitting.

Any commands to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

option 1: click the wolf with a **BARE** hand because some time other items well mess it up

option 2: Try to reset your game/device in my experience this fixes 90% of problems.

Comment: I literally said I can't make my pets unsit, even right-clicking it

Comment: @JohnJopet that's why i said bare hand, sorry i was just trying to help...

Comment: it's alright, thank you anyways